# Ubuntu - Full root partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk

I have a Ubuntu server which has a full partition:

```
# df -hq
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        50G   50G     0 100% /
/dev/sdd1       100G   80G   20G 20%  /testA
...
```

However the output from the summarixe is:

```
# sudo du -hs /
130G    /
```

When I try to troubleshoot the issue by summarizing it also includes different disks:

```
#  sudo du -hsx /* | sort -rh | head -n 40
70G     /testA
20G     /opt
300M    /home
```

Two quesitons:

- Where do I begin to clean up?
- If cleaning up isn't an option, but rather extend, how is this done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `sudo du -x / | sort -n | tail -50`. Where do you begin to clean up? No one but you knows.

Comment: You can try `ncdu`.

Comment: `/var/log`, `/var/tmp/` and `/var/cache/` is always a good start

Comment: `sudo du -hd 1 /` output?